# What is the cause of this PHP exception?

Tags: 8

When I disable the *Database logging* or the *Views UI* module from a Drupal 8 site, I get the following error.

> Drupal\Component\Serialization\Exception\InvalidDataTypeException: yaml_parse(): end of stream reached without finding document 0 in Drupal\Component\Serialization\YamlPecl::errorHandler()

What might be causing it?

Comment: Run a yaml liniter against the code in question

Comment: @kevin only problem is we are not aware which yaml file is causing this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was faulty yaml file which caused the php exception. Follow script helped 

`"for filename in find . -type f -name "*.yml" 
do
  php -r '
  $filename = "'$filename'"; 
 $string = file_get_contents($filename); 
 $parsed = yaml_parse($string);
 if ($parsed === FALSE)
 {
    echo " $filename is borked \n"; 
 }'
done"`

source https://docs.acquia.com/article/pecl-yaml-serialization-errors

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have an invalid yaml file. you have a syntax error in it so the yaml library cannot "see" or parse the internal yaml document properly.

Comment: how to find the bad file , we have 100s of configuration file.